# ImageJ can't find JVM although OpenJDK 8 is installed

Tags: java, openjdk, jvm

I installed ImageJ (`sudo apt install imagej`) on Ubuntu 16.04, but it does not work:

```
$ imagej
Open other images in this ImageJ panel as follows:
  imagej -p 1 <image1> [<image2> ... <imageN>]

No JVM found to run ImageJ
Please apt-get install a JVM to run ImageJ or 
set JAVA_HOME if it's not a JVM from a Debian Package.
```

However, OpenJDK 8 is installed:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

What should I do to get ImageJ running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. It's Reported at launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagej/+bug/1579185) titled *imagej won't start (xenial)*. Which is itself a duplicate of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagej/+bug/1556997), which says *JAVA_HOME auto-detection fails due to whitespace in update-java-alternatives output*

It is fixed in [Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=820097) and fixed version is included in Yakkety.

There are several fixes reported in the bug report. One fix that worked for me was manually exporting `JAVA_HOME` and starting from terminal

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
imagej
```

Someone reported that a build of Yakkety works for Xenial too. It can be downloaded from here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagej/1.50i+dfsg-1/+build/9642507

I downloaded that build and it works without any workaround!

---

Another workaround is directly editing `/usr/bin/imagej` file as suggested by ByteCommander (Thanks to him). Around line 32, changing the line

```
JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/sbin/update-java-alternatives -l | grep openjdk | sort | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 3)
```

to

```
JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/sbin/update-java-alternatives -l | grep openjdk | sort | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 3)
```

that is basically inserting `tr -s ' ' |` before `cut ...`

Comment: I edited `/usr/bin/imagej`, which seems to be the cleanest fix. Around line 32, change `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/sbin/update-java-alternatives -l | grep openjdk | sort | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 3)` to `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/sbin/update-java-alternatives -l | grep openjdk | sort | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 3)` (by inserting `tr -s ' ' | `). Maybe you want to add that workaround as well?

Comment: @ByteCommander done. Check if that's OK

Comment: Yup, that's the other workaround suggested on Launchpad. Great :)